# Android App crash with dialog

Tags: android, dialog, gps

I`m getting the GPS coordination of the device inside an AsyncTask class (by getLocation method) but, If the GPS is disable, I open a dialog that able the user to transfer to the "setting" area and turn the GPS "on" or cancel. The App crash every time the the dialog alert has open before the user even press at one of the buttons. How can I solve it ?

```
    public class StarTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,ArrayList<Song>>{

    final int k_ThreadSleepTime = 3000;
    final int k_MaxThreadTries = 7;
    double latitude = 0;
    double longitude = 0;
    GPSTracker gps;
    TestMain client;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        gps = new GPSTracker(getApplication());
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Song> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ArrayList<Song> list = new ArrayList();
        client = new TestMain();
        int tries = 0;
        String o;
        getLocation();
        String url = builtURL();
        try {
            String jsonPageStr = client.doGetRequest(url);
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonPageStr);
            userId = obj.getJSONObject("info").getInt("user_id");
            isWait = (wait.equals("true"));

            while (isWait && tries < k_MaxThreadTries) {
                url = builtURL();
                jsonPageStr = client.doGetRequest(url);
                obj = new JSONObject(jsonPageStr);
                if (!(obj.equals("") || obj.equals(null))) {
                    isWait = (wait.equals("true"));
                }
                tries++;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(k_ThreadSleepTime);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if(tries == k_MaxThreadTries) {
                //exit the App
                onMyDestroy();
            }
    }

    private String builtURL() {}

    private void getLocation() {
        if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
            latitude = gps.getLatitude();
            longitude = gps.getLongitude();

        } else {
            // can't get location
            // GPS or Network is not enabled
            // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings

            //gps.showSettingsAlert();

            showSettingsAlert();
        }
        gps.stopUsingGPS();
    }

    public void showSettingsAlert(){

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

                // Setting Dialog Title
                alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

                // Setting Dialog Message
                alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

                // On pressing Settings button
                alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                        hasBeenNoGps = true;
                    }
                });

                // on pressing cancel button
                alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                        hasBeenNoGps = true;
                        onMyDestroy();
                    }
                });

                // Showing Alert Message
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Song> aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing UI operations on `showSettingsAlert()` which is called during `doInBackground()` of your `AsyncTask`. The allowed approach is to keep all operations involving UI away from `doInBackground()`. Here you could remove the else condition from `getLocation()` and rather implement it `onPreExecute()`. Like this,

```
 public class StarTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,ArrayList<Song>>{

    final int k_ThreadSleepTime = 3000;
    final int k_MaxThreadTries = 7;
    double latitude = 0;
    double longitude = 0;
    GPSTracker gps;
    TestMain client;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        gps = new GPSTracker(getApplication());
        if (!gps.canGetLocation()) {
           showSettingsAlert();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Song> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ArrayList<Song> list = new ArrayList();
        client = new TestMain();
        int tries = 0;
        String o;
        getLocation();
        String url = builtURL();
        try {
            String jsonPageStr = client.doGetRequest(url);
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonPageStr);
            userId = obj.getJSONObject("info").getInt("user_id");
            isWait = (wait.equals("true"));

            while (isWait && tries < k_MaxThreadTries) {
                url = builtURL();
                jsonPageStr = client.doGetRequest(url);
                obj = new JSONObject(jsonPageStr);
                if (!(obj.equals("") || obj.equals(null))) {
                    isWait = (wait.equals("true"));
                }
                tries++;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(k_ThreadSleepTime);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if(tries == k_MaxThreadTries) {
                //exit the App
                onMyDestroy();
            }
    }

    private void getLocation() {
        if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
            latitude = gps.getLatitude();
            longitude = gps.getLongitude();

        } 
        gps.stopUsingGPS();
    }
```

Comment: Hi @siris_cac, I try that but it still crush. I have this exception: E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: maimon.milab.blenders, PID: 25999
    android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: Looks like you're doing some other operation elsewhere that is running on the main thread. Show your logs.

Comment: Now it telling me :     android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run a UI thread in a background thread (inside your AsyncTask), what you can do is create a global dialog in your AsyncTask class and show it on *doInBackground* method and then close it *onPostExecute()*. You will need a *Context* for your dialog.

Comment: Thanks @EdgarMarcoPolo, should I built the showSettingsAlert() method inside run?. Should I put the alertDialog.show() inside run ?

Comment: You don't need to use your runOnUiThread, you can delete that part, you just need your context (MainActivity.this) in your case to show the dialog, what you need to understand is that doInBackground is a thread in the background (it was made to run thing not in the UI Thread) and you are using runOnUiThread in a background thread.